# How to get woocommerce cart content without an action?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

With every photo upload, I create a woocommerce product and you might get the idea that at some point I will have lots of unused products. I save product id and image upload links to a text file.

What I am trying to do is to delete a product after 24 hours if it is not in cart and I want to do this with cron.

The problem I have is I do not understand how to make the global woocommerce properties available also for scheduled events (cron).

This is how I set a scheduled event:

```
add_action('daily_product_removal',  'delete_unused_products' );

function activate() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'daily_product_removal' );
}

function deactivate() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('daily_product_removal');
}
```

Woo in cart function:

```
function woo_in_cart($product_id) {
    global $woocommerce;

    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
        $_product = $val['data'];

        if($product_id == $_product->id ) {


       return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Main function:

```
function delete_unused_products() {

    $woocommerce = new Client(
        'site_link',
        'ck_numbers',
        'cs_numbers',
        [
            'wp_api' => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v1',
        ]
    );

    $myFile = "products.txt";

    $myFileLink = fopen($myFile, 'r');

    $products = [];

     while(!feof($myFileLink)) {
          $this_line = fgets($myFileLink);
          array_push($products,$this_line);
     }

     fclose($myFileLink);

     foreach($products as $i => $item) {

        $product = unserialize($item);
        $creation_date_from_file = $product->creation_date;
        $product_id = $product->product_id;

        $createDate = strtotime($creation_date_from_file);

        if (strtotime("$creation_date_from_file +1 day") <= time() && !woo_in_cart($product_id)) { // created more than 24 hours ago and is not added in cart

            $results = $woocommerce->delete('products/' . $product_id, ['force' => true]);

            if (file_exists($item->local_url)) {
                unlink($item->local_url);
            }
        if (file_exists($item->local_mockup_url)) {
            unlink($item->local_url);
        }

        file_put_contents($myFile, str_replace($i . "\r\n", "", file_get_contents($myFile))); // delete the line

    }
}
```

}

The problem I have is that If I run this function under woocommerce specific action hook, lets say:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents', 'delete_unused_products' );
```

Its fine, but If I run this as I want (through cron) I get errors, something like  $woocommerce->cart is not defined.

Can not wrap my head around how to make this work. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a serious flaw in your design. A cart is part of a session. An active session exists when a buyer is viewing a front-end page. But, when a cron job is run there is no buyer viewing a front-end page so there is no active session and hence no cart.